# how to access an object outside of the file in Node js and express?

Tags: node.js, express

I am working on node js and express. I have created two js files with the name hash.js and login.js. Hash.js file takes the username and password and generates token against the password. But the login.js file is unable to pick up the username.
I wanted to know a method through which I can access the users object in login.js file. Here is the screenshot of both the files. I although declared users=[] object in login.js file, but whenever I tried to login, it gave me the message of user not found.

[Hash.js]

```
      const express = require("express");
      const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
      const router = express.Router();
      const app = express();
      let users = [];
      app.use(express.json());


      router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
            try {
                const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
                const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);
                users.push({username: req.body.username, password: passwordHash});
               res.json(users);
             } 
            catch (e) {
                 res.status(500).send(e.toString());
         }
   });
       router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
        try {
          const user = users.find(user => user.username = req.body.username);
          console.log(user);
       if (!user) {
          res.status(400).send('User Not Found!');
        }
       if (await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)) {
          res.send('LoggedIn');
         } else {
             res.send('Not Valid User!');
         }
    }   catch (e) {
            console.log(e.toString());
      }
  })
```

module.exports=router;

[app.js]

```
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static('public'));
const jwt=require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const path=require('path');
const hash=require("./hash");
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

const port=3000;

// Import routes

const authRouter = require("./routes/auth.js");
const messagesRouter = require("./routes/messages.js");



app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
  res.send("hello world");

});
// Setup all the routes
    app.use("/api/messages", messagesRouter);
    app.use("/api/auth", authRouter);
    app.use("/", hash);
    
app.use("/", hash);
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
});
```

Comment: Seems like you are not exporting anything from the hash.js file, Also please add the code as a <codeblock/>. It will be much useful for people viewing it

Comment: Yes, I am not exporting anything. But I am wondering how to access users object so that I can login easily.

Comment: If that is the case, Then you should wrap all the code in one file, Or you should export the members from the other file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have separated hash.js & login.js, you need to create another users.js to temporary store the data. Just show you the way. I still recommend to combine hash.js, login.js & users.js under 1 route as your authentication route because routes will be getting many for complicated app. Furthermore, user.js is just for testing, you will need database like MySQL, mongoDB & etc.

users.js

```
const users = [];

module.exports = users;
```

hash.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const router = express.Router();
const users = require("./users");

router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
    const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);
    console.log(passwordHash);
    users.push({ username: req.body.username, password: passwordHash });
    res.json(users);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send(e.toString());
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

login.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const router = express.Router();
const users = require("./users");

router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = users.find((user) => user.username === req.body.username);
    console.log(user);
    if (!user) {
      res.status(400).send("User Not Found!");
    }
    if (await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)) {
      res.send("LoggedIn");
    } else {
      res.send("Not Valid User!");
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.toString());
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Then import the hash.js to your server.js. I have created simple login.ejs & register.ejs in "views" to test. It works.

```
const hash = require("./hash");
const login = require("./login");

app.use(express.json());
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  res.render("login.ejs");
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("register.ejs");
});

app.use("/", hash);
app.use("/", login);

app.listen(3000);
```

register.ejs

```
<h1>Register</h1>
<form action="/register" method="POST">
  <div>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="username" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Register</button>
</form>
```

login.ejs

```
<h1>Login</h1>
<form action="/login" method="POST">
  <div>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: But what if I want that in separate files? Is it possible?

Comment: You can reorganize as above but I still recommend to put all under 1 route for better maintenance in future. Thanks

Comment: okay I have combined both the register and login code in the file hash.js. Now how should I provide the route in server.js?

Comment: I mean the main file is hash.js. In that file I provide the path for /register and /login.

Comment: You mean you have hash.js only? You don't have server.js or app.js?

Comment: If you have hash.js only, then move all the codes from login.js, hash.js & users.js into server.js that I have created above. Change router.post to app.post, remove express.Router & module.exports and test out. It should be working fine. But I still recommend to follow the above, later you will learn about MVC which is easier to maintain your codes. Thanks

Comment: I mean the main file is hash.js. In that file I provide the path for /register and /login. Now if I first want to access the register file and then the login file in postman. how would I do that? I mean I just want to generate the token from register file and login with login file without any form. Simply in postman .

Comment: I have app.js. The code you provided above the html forms are so useful, I will definitely need them. But I am assigned a task to simply generate the token and do login with username and password.  So what route should I give that is confusing me. I am following this tutorial, I want to do exactly the same as this tutorial.  https://blog.devgenius.io/salt-and-hash-password-using-bcrypt-in-nodejs-3df1b7d23705 .. I have done this in app.js file and it worked perfectly. But I don't want to full my app.js with codes. I want to do this in another file

Comment: Ok, you can follow the codes & files above. First your run node app.js in terminal. Go to postman change method to "POST", then key in the url as http://localhost:3000/register for registration, type in username & password, then click "Send", change url to http://localhost:3000/login, type in the username & password, click "Send". You should be able to see "LoggedIn".

Comment: I put that link in the postman localhost:3000/register but it said It can't find the link. I have put the register and login file in hash.js .. So in app.js file I have written const hash=require("./hash");  .. but how will it know that the codes are written in hash.js... I mean I have written the link like this too localhost:3000/hash/register it still didn't pick the link.. I am trying to paste the screenshot by editing my question but its not uploading I don't know why

Comment: Have you started the server?

Comment: yes I started by node app.js but I think its mixing the links. Because I have included the codes in hash.js file and inside that I have written router.post("./register") for registration and router.post("./login") .  Now the link should be localhost:3000/hash/register and localhost:3000/hash/login ??

Comment: Can you provide your email kindly so that I can send you the screenshots?

Comment: Is ok, I can't share my personal info here or you can amend your codes in the questions? Thanks

Comment: I have edit my code above. You can see I have put the codes in the file hash.js. Now what will be the route so that I can access register and login code. ?? bcz I don't know the route should contain the file name like hash/register. will it work?

Comment: OK, export router at hash.js. Import it at your app.js by requiring hash.js, add app.use("/", hash) in your app.js. Run server, use url http://localhost:3000/register & login, in Postman, no need to add the file name.

Comment: I have updated the code with what you guided. I used post method in postman with localhost:3000/register. it is giving error that it can't find <pre>Cannot POST /register</pre>

Comment: What could be the error?

Comment: Are you using desktop agent? Should be desktop agent only since it is local server. Check  bottom right of Postman.

Comment: I am using putty. The error is that it is not getting the register route. I am not using register.ejs and login.ejs.

Comment: I thought you are using Postman, I am not familiar with Putty. If you can use Postman, just download the desktop agent, your codes are ok already, just need to use correct settings in Postman. One more thing, you have repeated app.use("/", hash), just delete one of it. Thanks

Comment: Putty is the server where I write my codes and use postman to check it

Comment: Ok, you can explore more on it, your codes are ok already, I start the server & test in Postman, it works.

Comment: Thank you so much the method worked. Now I want to do the login through the form you have created. Should I run the get method in postman to make the login form appear?

Comment: Glad that I can help, please help to accept the answer, appreciate you help. You can use GET in Postman to retrieve the database, it will should in JSON format. Thanks

Comment: And does this login.ejs file should be created in a special folder or something? should I provide the link in server file? or this is enough? app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  res.render("login.ejs");
});

Comment: http://localhost/login. I am loading this in postman it is not showing me the form to submit my username and password.

Comment: You can search for MVC, too much to explain here. It consists of Controllers, Routes & your server.js. EJS or other templating files normally are kept in "views" folder and add the path in your server.js. You can type key words like this in google to search for example "CRUD MySQL Nodejs" or "CRUD MongoDB Nodejs" .

Comment: ah I know about MVC. No I want just simple html form to just check my login page is accepting username and password. I am not using mvc, just want to create an html file in in my server folder

Comment: Ok, just create register.ejs & login.ejs in "views" folder. Follow the server.js source codes that I have posted. Go to browser url type in http:localhost:3000/register to register user then go to /login to login. Remember to npm install ejs.

Comment: I don't have views folder. can I just create it where my hash.js and app.js files are??

Comment: You can follow this tutorial, it is regarding EJS + Node JS. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application

Comment: I want to use login.html as static file. I want to load login.html file and load the data how to do it?

Comment: You can go through these examples. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/use-expressjs-to-deliver-html-files & https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/nodejs-serving-static-files-in-express